# Property Navigation Reference in EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first, fluent

In my class `produc`, I have a collection of photos.
One of the photos in this collection represents the main product photo.

**My class of products**

```
public class Product
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Photo> Photos { get; set; }
    public virtual Photo Photo { get; set; }
}
```

The property `photo` must point to one photo in photo collection.

**ProducsConfiguration**

To generate the schema of the database, use the following configuration:

```
public class ProductConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Product>
{
    public ProductConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(p => p.ID)
            .Property(p => p.ID)
            .IsRequired();

        Property(p => p.Name)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(65);

        HasMany(p => p.Photos).WithMany().Map(m => m.ToTable("ProductPhotos"));
        ...???...
    }
}
```

**Question**

How would the configuration (USING FLUENT CONFIGURATION of EF) for relating the property `photos` as a reference to one of the photos in the collection `Photos` ??

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that was a typo and you are referring to the `Photo` property, there's nothing else you need to do.

By default, `Photo` will be a reference to a Photo. Technically, the Photo doesn't *have* to be part of the `Photos` collection (and there's no way to make EF validate that), but it will accomplish what you need (having a "main" photo)